# Laplace transform of Mass spring damper differential equation - Issues with input

Tags: differential-equations, integral-transforms

```
de = x''[t] + 6 x'[t] + 8 x[t] == 10
80 + 6 Derivative[1][x][t] + (x^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t] == 10

Initial = {x[0] -> 0, x'[0] -> 0}

Lde = LaplaceTransform[de, t, s]
80/s - Derivative[1][x][0] == 10/s

Lde = Lde /. Initial
80/s == 10/s

Solve[Lde, LaplaceTransform[x[t], t, s]]
Solve::ivar: 10/s is not a valid variable.
```

Hello, using the trail version of mathmatica I have a Differetial equation (de) and want to find the laplace transform of it and model X[t] and x[s]. Ive used various resources to get to this point but cannot get past the last line.

It states that 10/s is not a valid variable - but this is my input???

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have some existing definitions that are causing problems?  Perhaps try again with a fresh kernel (via the menu "Evaluation > Quit Kernel")

Comment: `8 x[t]` is replaced by `80` in the first line, suggesting that `x[t]` has already been defined as `10` in code preceding that in the question.  This issue probably invalidates everything that follows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lt = LaplaceTransform[de, t, s] /. Initial;
sol = Solve[lt, LaplaceTransform[x[t], t, s]];
InverseLaplaceTransform[sol[[1, 1, 2]], s, t]
```

[image]

```
DSolve[{x''[t] + 6 x'[t] + 8 x[t] == 10, x[0] == 0, x'[0] == 0}, x[t], t]
```

[image]

```
Plot[x[t] /. %, {t, 0, 30}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for that Maple and after starting a new kernel - (cheers mikado) it worked. Going to construct it so I can understand the response of MSD systems better.